# How to execute sql query in elasticsearch Nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, elasticsearch

Am using Elasticsearch in nodejs using npm [elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch),

Here, how can i execute sql queries in elasticsearch?

Is there any npm modules or plugin to execute sql queries in elasticsearch ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read docs? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

Comment: yeah i read that, there is no option to execute raw sql queries @Molda

Comment: @Kalai Did you found your answer?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/sql_query_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute SQL queries directly, but you can convert them to Lucene syntax and execute them
so, the where clause would look like

```
field1:value AND (field2:(a b c) OR field3:[* 5])
```

you can use the q param to pass the lucene query

```
       this.client.search({
        index: 'my-index',
        from: 0,
        track_total_hits: true,
        size: 10,
        q: 'field1:value AND (field2:(a b c) OR field3:[* 5])',
        sort: 'field1 ASC'
    });
```

I would encourage you to look at [ANTLR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antlr4) if you want to convert from SQL to Lucene.